# receptacle not working in kitchen

Tags: electrical

House built in 1997 a receptacle in the kitchen that the coffee brewer has always been plugged into suddenly stopped working. I checked the gfi's in that room none of them tripped, checked the other receptacles and they all work. This one receptacle is the only one not working. I took the old receptacle out it only had 2 wires and a ground. the white wire where the connection was on the screw looked like it was slightly melted. I replaced that receptacle with a new one just like the old one, attached it just like it was removed, and it still don't work. what could my problem be?

Comment: Is this on the same circuit as other outlets or its own circuit?

Comment: Did you use the side-screws or the backstabs when hooking up the new receptacle?

Comment: used the side screws and I am not sure if it is on its own circuit or not but all other receptacles in the entire house work except this one

Comment: Check the connections on the receptacle which feeds this one. Look for a loose wire connection.

Comment: Was the screw gud-n-tight or was it loosey goosey?

Comment: how will I know which receptacle feeds it like I said all the other receptacles work all over the house. the screws are good and tight

Comment: Do you have any electrical test equipment, such as a multimeter, a non-contact voltage tester, or even a plug-in circuit tester?

Comment: Go online or to a home store and get a plug in tester: https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=greenlee+gt-10&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=177791418210&hvpos=1t1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=936892197774126479&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=kwd-10490069981&ref=pd_sl_8vun98mq9a_e Compare the readings of the nonworking receptacle to working ones.

Comment: I used the multi meter to test it and nothing coming up at all on that meter. no movement period

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have three conductors in your junction box, it means you are at the end of that circuit. The burning of the insulation is a concern and probably indicates that you have had an overheating problem and that has probably caused your failure. You need to trace back to the preceding box and check it for loose connections or some other failure. Just because the preceding receptacle is working does not mean that there is not a problem in that box. (forgive the double negative). I have attached a rough drawing to let you know what you are looking at.
[image]

If you can't find the problem in that box the you have damaged your wiring and you will need to ring out the circuit to find the problem.

Good luck

Comment: does the circuit always go left to right. this plug is the 1st plug in the room as you enter the door way on the left so there is no other plug to the left of it unless its in the room before you enter into this one. to the right of this bad one is a single gfci receptacle that works

Comment: It usually goes toward the panel, but that is just a guess. No matter what it should be protected to A GFCI so go that direction. It's really just a matter of opening up each receptacle and taking a look.